# How can I deliver a TypeScript interface to my command?

Tags: typescript, dependencies

I am creating a TypeScript command that can be configured with custom scripts. I'd like these custom scripts to be written in TypeScript and transpiled "on the fly".
Something like : `myCommand script.ts`

I have several questions :

1. The command must transmit an interface to the script, hence the script needs to be able to load the interface definition I can manage this with a dependency (import 'node_modules/myCommand/types') but how do I test during development phase ?
2. Is there a way to trigger tsc from within a script ?
3. The transpiling will generate new files that I need to store somewhere, any best practice ?

If you are aware of any project doing something similar, I'd be curious to see how it works.

Thx !

Comment: The typescript compiler has an api that you can use from node https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Comment: @AlexWayne thx for the info !